# Unable to redirect the output in another page(HTML,Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, geolocation

I want to find the latitude and longitude of current location and print the same on another page on button click.
Though i am successful in getting the latitude and longitude but unable to print/redirect on another page.

can someone please help. please find the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
<p id="demo"></p>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<h2 >Geo-Logical Application</h2><br>
<p>Click the button to get Longitude and Latitude for your current position.</p><br>

<form action="Listing.html">
<button type="submit" onclick="getLocation()">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to redirect the output to listing page.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

- Use `window.location` to redirect to another page  &
- pass `event` to `getLocation` to stop default submission :

Modify as following  :

```
function getLocation(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(p){
               showPosition(p);
                // 
               window.location="Listing.html?lat="+p.coords.latitude+"&lgt="+p.coords.longitude; 
         });
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
```

And HTML becomes :

```
<form action="Listing.html">
<button type="submit" onclick="getLocation(event)">Submit</button>
</form>
```

---

If your page handles GET parameters :

```
window.location="Listing.html?lat="+p.coords.latitude+"&lgt="+p.coords.longitude;
```

else, use `sessionStorage` to have stateful application  :

`sessionStorage.setItem('POS',JSON.stringify(position.coords))` and in  `Listing.html` , get it by : `JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('POS'))`

Comment: It's not working, though i will look for sessionStorage.

Comment: `sessionStorage.setItem('POS',JSON.stringify(position.coords))` and in  `Listing.html` , get it by : `JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('POS'))`

Comment: Thanks for your kind advice but its also not working

Comment: Actually it was not showing any error but desired output was not displayed. Although with your advice i used localstorage and it worked.`var Latitude = localStorage.getItem('latitudeGet');
     var Longitude= localStorage.getItem('longitudeGet');` Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should not have a p element in the script.  It should be in the body.  Also, your script tag should be at the end of the body because it has code that modifies the DOM.  The showPosition(position) function should come before the getLocation() function because you use showPosition in getLocation.

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't catch the part about in listing.html

Comment: Those are just some other problems